# What is the difference between String.replace/4 and Regex.replace/4?

Tags: elixir

I'm using Regexes (Regices?) for the first time in Elixir and came upon two functions which, at first glance, seem identical, save for the ordering of their arguments: [`String.replace/4`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/String.html#replace/4) and [`Regex.replace/4`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Regex.html#replace/4).

Both of them take a string, a pattern, a replacement, and a list of options, and return the replaced string.

Is there any difference between the two? In what case should I use one over the other?

Comment: You can clearly see the usage difference from the docs. The goal of these functions is the same. Why ask? What is your *specific* problem?

Comment: "In what case should I use one over the other?" is my specific problem.

Comment: It is up to you if you want to use a regex, what is your input? What is the expected output?

Comment: This is not a question about how to use regexes, but a question about the language design of elixir and the difference between two implementations of the same functionality. I have, upon reflection, removed the 'regex' tag from the question, as I no longer deem it appropriate.

Comment: Ok, better, but still, you see the difference in the signatures - `String.replace` can perform literal string replacements and it can take a list of strings as the *pattern* argument, `Regex.replace` always searches with a regex. This is again clear from the docs.

Comment: I answered to this question here: https://gist.github.com/am-kantox/bfa82ff705ca448efd93c30e08a9631d I am positive the question is legit and has a concrete answer.

Comment: That's a good answer. If you post it here I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: We cannot post answers to closed questions, that’s SO rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String.replace/4` provides additional functionality over `Regex.replace/4`. It's equivalent to `Regex.replace/4` in the specific situation when:

- The `pattern` argument is a [`%Regex{}`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Regex.html#t:t/0) struct.
- the `replacement` argument is a binary or a single-arity function.

You can see `String.replace/4` calling `Regex.replace/4` in this situation in the [source code](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.9.1/lib/elixir/lib/string.ex#L1346).

For regular expressions, it doesn't matter which one you use.

However, there are many ways to use `String.replace/4` without a regular expression. They are listed in the [documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/String.html#replace/4-examples), so I don't think it's necessary to repeat them here. It could be a good idea to state what you are actually trying to do, because it may be that you have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and that in Elixir using a regular expression isn't the best tool for the task you are undertaking.

Comment: Yeah, `For regular expressions, it doesn't matter which one you use.` was mostly what I was looking for. I realize I phrased my question somewhat vaguely, as it was really more about the rationale behind Elixir's language design than about a specific programming problem -- perhaps this question would have been better suited to the Software Engineering Stack Exchange.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, Both of them take string, a pattern and replacement. The difference is, String will replace the string with "replacement string" if the pattern string exist in the input string. 
Ex: String.replace("abc", "a", "A") - this will result in Abc. It will look for the search string "a" and replace the string with "A".

Whereas in Regex.Replace - here the search pattern will be considered as regular expression unlike string.

Ex: Regex.replace(~r/b/, "abc", "d") - This will result in "adc" . Here the pattern "b" will be considered as regular expression.

To make you clear, Regex.replace(~r/\d/ "A2B3C", "-"), this will result in A-B-C. Here the search pattern is \d - which mean any number. Regex will replace the numbers with "-" in the given string. Where as if you use the same search pattern for string String.replace("A2B3C", "d", "-") - this will result in "A2B3C". Nothing gets replaced.

Look at https://www.regular-expressions.info for more information about the regex patterns

Comment: I don't believe this to be correct, as the docs for `String.replace/4` state that "The pattern may be a string, a regular expression, or a compiled pattern."

Comment: Wrong, `String.replace` also allows a *regex* based replacement.